# Swift SearchBar cannot filter data

Tags: swift, xcode, swift4, searchbar

I have setup UISearchBar things. but I'm getting error says.

> Cannot assign value of type '[cellData]' to type '[String]'

here's the code

```
struct cellData {
let jobTitle : AnyObject?
let companyName : String?
let jobLocation : String?
let jobDescription : String?
let jobReq : String?
let firstPosterImage : AnyObject?
let secondPosterImage : AnyObject?
let createdAt : Date

init(jobTitle: AnyObject?, companyName: String? = nil, jobLocation: String? = nil ,jobDescription: String? = nil, jobReq:String? = nil, firstPosterImage: AnyObject? = nil, secondPosterImage: AnyObject? = nil, timeStamp:Double) {

    self.jobTitle = jobTitle
    self.companyName = companyName
    self.jobLocation = jobLocation
    self.jobDescription = jobDescription
    self.jobReq = jobReq
    self.firstPosterImage = firstPosterImage
    self.secondPosterImage = secondPosterImage
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timeStamp/1000) 

}
```

}

```
var cellDataArray = [cellData]()
var filtered = [String]()


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {


    if searchText.isEmpty {
        isSearching = false
        tableView.reloadData()

    } else {
        isSearching = true
        filtered  = cellDataArray.filter({($0.jobTitle?.lowercased?.contains(searchText.lowercased()))!})
        tableView.reloadData()
    }


}
```

I'm getting error in this line

```
filtered  = cellDataArray.filter({($0.jobTitle?.lowercased?.contains(searchText.lowercased()))!})
```

. notice that CellDataArray has the struct of cellData.
and I'm using searchBar in tableView.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that `cellDataArray` and `filtered` are of 2 different data types ( `String` and struct `CellData` ) so you can't simply assign one to the other without a conversion like

```
let res  = cellDataArray.filter({($0.jobTitle?.lowercased?.contains(searchText.lowercased()))!})
filtered  = res.map { $0.anyProprtyInside } // property should be a String
```

What you may mean is to declare filtered as

```
var filtered = [CellData]() // start structs / classes / protocols with uppercase letter
```